# Firebase Cloud Function Log Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Total nube question from a hobby developer - appreciate any help.
4 years ago (pre-COVID) I had a mobile app developed using Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Function that moved a bunch of my code server side to monitor for database changes and then calculate values and make other changes to the database. Just an app for personal use. Total hobby.

Haven't touched it, or done ANY other development since. Now I'm trying to update everything - including shake the rust off my development skills. Have the app running again and it's interacting with the FB Realtime Database just fine. I've been able to restore the Cloud Function, can get to the code, update it from Node.js8 --> 18, and have it active,  and it's triggering when the database is changed. But, erroring right at the beginning. I'm sure this is a "you need to update things for new version, parameters, etc." situation. But, haven't been able to find any details on the settings/parameters that need to change.

The log error is shown below:

[image: Cloud Function Log Error]

I assume the 'name' it is referring to is from the package.json and/or package-lock.json, so I'm also showing those below.

Any ideas / suggestions? THANKS!

package.json:

```
{
  "engines": { "node": "18" },
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

package-lock.json (just the beginning shown since it was so long):

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "requires": true,
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/app": {
      "version": "0.3.16",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@firebase/app/-/app-0.3.16.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-rZMu9EwiQsLVyNd5R847OY5rVxZ99OEbw/Vf/AxfUFb8TyA+Fp/sgwnuB+M4xltkTECh1ouR4pByg1mJgnYzMQ==",
      "requires": {
        "@firebase/app-types": "0.3.9",
        "@firebase/util": "0.2.13",
        "dom-storage": "2.1.0",
        "tslib": "1.9.3",
        "xmlhttprequest": "1.8.0"
      }
    },
    "@firebase/app-types": {
      "version": "0.3.9",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@firebase/app-types/-/app-types-0.3.9.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-XI+jfMTghpXnK13oCPPMF69AV1dn1HsmjPZvobtyy2K4gzPWIRpavLNA9+yzThHBJQCbTJa2Igqe1H0tZ5+bTA=="
    },
    "@firebase/database": {
      "version": "0.3.19",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@firebase/database/-/database-0.3.19.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-o1/1BXE3t2UOpntGDD9/eAGG4OqM8KtLEB4l2Ual/B6GPXmUOS7m1RP36QHmLfCFcnzo4z29gZHnbk0Tq7XSVg==",
      "requires": {
        "@firebase/database-types": "0.3.10",
        "@firebase/logger": "0.1.12",
        "@firebase/util": "0.2.13",
        "faye-websocket": "0.11.1",
        "tslib": "1.9.3"
      }
    },
    "@firebase/database-types": {
      "version": "0.3.10",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@firebase/database-types/-/database-types-0.3.10.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-yREigbf0wOaIIbipX2yK7O5YU0IlbsPFSET8MZHvesAB9b4/AZcDZ2zeJiXZTWmxb5EDbngFsUvmGBuxRNPsfw=="
    },
    "@firebase/logger": {
      "version": "0.1.12",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@firebase/logger/-/logger-0.1.12.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-8IK99J/gwl0hRRogYQVmvk43gu949uPvvqdM0Bn36/PhveHYs6zIPavD+DuaTkn78L3Wzd+/XPNWWod7qNna+A=="
    },
```

The Cloud Function is getting called/triggered, but it errors right from the start.

Comment: You should seriously consider updating all your dependencies and learning how things work again using the documentation. 4 years is a very long time for a product that evolves. So many things have changed so much that you're likely to keep spending finding little problems all over. It's easier just start fresh and try to port whatever code you have to a modern project structure.

Comment: Hi todd ,have you tried the suggestions below? Do let me know if the below information was helpful?

Comment: I started things over with a new Firebase project, but have set that aside for now and reactivated similar code I had initially developed within the app. I'm trying to use this app for a guys weekend event in a week, so I'm focused on getting it working quicklyl (but maybe not as efficiently as with server-side code). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an issue with the `firebase-functions` module is very old. The latest version is [4.4.0.](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/releases) Upgrade it with the below command:

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest
```

Also make sure you need to update the `firebase-function` module within the `functions directory`

```
cd functions
npm install firebase-functions@latest
```

Then update `firebase.json` to

```
"runtime": "nodejs18"
```

Also make sure that the installed dependencies in the `package.json` are compatible with the `Firebase-functions` version.

Also as @Doug Stevenson suggested in the comments, it's better to start fresh and try to port whatever code you have to a modern project structure. Since you are using 4 years the product has evolved a lot in the meantime. You can check with this [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).

Comment: Thanks guys. I will likely just start fresh and then copy the code and build it out function-by-function. I was expecting this because of the 4 year gap. But, had been surprised at how easily I was able to update Visual Studio and the code in the app itself and get the realtime database working again. Was hoping for similar results with the cloud functions.

Really appreciate the upgrade commands you've included. Will give those a shot and see where it goes.

Comment: I started things over with a new Firebase project, but have set that aside for now and reactivated similar code I had initially developed within the app. I'm trying to use this app for a guys weekend event in a week, so I'm focused on getting it working quicklyl (but maybe not as efficiently as with server-side code). Thanks for the help.